# MediaWiki API: can it be used to create new articles programatically?

Tags: python, bots, mediawiki-api

I've been charged with migrating a large amount of simple web pages into wikiMedia articles. I've been researching the API and PyWikiBot but it seems that all it allows you to do is edit and retrieve what is already there. Can these tools be used to create a brand new article with content, a title and links to itself etc?

If not, can anyone suggest a way to make large scale automated entries to the MediaWiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new article simply by editing a page that doesn't exist yet.